# Corrupted JSON encoding in Perl (missign comma)

Tags: json, perl

My custom code (on Perl) give next wrong JSON, missing comma between blocks:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "{#LOGFILEPATH}": "/tmp/QRZ2007.tcserverlogs",
        "{#LOGFILE}": "QRZ2007"
    } **missing comma** {
        "{#LOGFILE}": "ARZ2007",
        "{#LOGFILEPATH}": "/tmp/ARZ2007.tcserverlogs"
    }]
}
```

My terrible code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use File::Basename;
    use utf8;
    use JSON;
    binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";


    my $dir = $ARGV[0];    
    my $json = JSON->new->utf8->space_after;
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    print '{"data": [';
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

        next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

        next unless ($file =~ m/\.tcserverlogs$/);
        my $fullPath = "$dir/$file";
        my $filenameshort = basename($file,  ".tcserverlogs");

        my $data_to_json = {"{#LOGFILEPATH}"=>$fullPath,"{#LOGFILE}"=>$filenameshort};
        my $data_to_json = {"{#LOGFILEPATH}"=>$fullPath,"{#LOGFILE}"=>$filenameshort};
        print $json->encode($data_to_json);

    }

    print ']}'."\n";
    closedir(DIR);
    exit 0;
```

Dear Team i am not a programmer, please any idea how fix it, thank you!

Comment: Your code is fine. You're not printing a comma, so there is no comma. You are not using the JSON module as it's intended to be used. You should create one data structure and encode it in one go. The JSON module does not support step-by-step conversion. Also, you declare `$data_to_json` twice. Your program will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not print a comma, you will not get a comma.

You are trying to build your own JSON string from pre-encoded pieces of smaller data structures. That will not work unless you tell Perl when to put commas. You could do that, but it's easier to just collect all the data into a Perl data structure that is equivalent to the JSON string you want to produce, and encode the whole thing in one go when you're done.

```
my $dir  = $ARGV[0];
my $json = JSON->new->utf8->space_after;
my @data;

opendir( DIR, $dir ) or die $!;
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {

    next unless ( -f "$dir/$file" );
    next unless ( $file =~ m/\.tcserverlogs$/ );
    my $fullPath = "$dir/$file";
    my $filenameshort = basename( $file, ".tcserverlogs" );

    my $data_to_json = { "{#LOGFILEPATH}" => $fullPath, "{#LOGFILE}" => $filenameshort };
    push @data, $data_to_json;
}
closedir(DIR);

print $json->encode( { data => \@data } );
```

Comment: What about when you are working with large data sets that are greater than memory can hold?

Comment: @DanielFoust I am not aware of a JSON implementation in Perl that allows chunking of data on encoding. https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#INCREMENTAL-PARSING talks about parsing incrementally, but not writing out pieces bit by bit. One could build something that keeps looking at the next value to come up to decide whether to put a comma at the end and encode each individual item, then enclosing it like OP did.

Comment: That's essentially what I did.  I check if the does not exist.  If it does not exist, use JSON::XS to write hash converted to json to file, else, open the file and print ",\n$json";

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer @Daniel. It sounds useful.